# Ruby on rails - Changing hyperlinks to table columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've made a list with hyper links to columns in a table called "Categories", there are 5 categories and the first set of code below makes hyperlinks to all 5.

I want to make a dropdown menu, but only show two of the categories, instead of all 5. Currently, i'm just using a href to the url, but is there some other way I can link to two columns in the "Categories" table?

Links:

```
<ul>
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.name, items_path(category: category.name) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Dropdown Menu:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Canon
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/items?category=Canon+Camera">Canon Cameras</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/items?category=Canon+Lens">Canon Lenses</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `take()` or `limit()` methods to limit how many items you want to get:

```
<ul>
    <% Category.take(2).each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.name, items_path(category: category.name) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That worked great, although is there any way to only select number 3 and 4 inside the take() method?

Comment: Use `offset()` method. `limit(2).offset(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your question "can link to two columns in the "Categories" table?" - Please find my comment as:

SQL Approach:

> SELECT CONCAT('', "name", "title") AS "name" FROM categories;

Rails Approach: <%= link_to "#{category.name} #{category.title}", items_path(category: category.name) %>